# How to stop vue error messaging in code in vscode from the vetur extension

Tags: vue.js, vetur

I have the vetur extension installed which handles error messaging in code. The problem is that my code works perfectly but the vetur extensions shows all red lines under my code which I don't want.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem[image]

Comment: Show error message please

Comment: Vetur is deprecated. Switch to Volar.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Vue.js V2, then you can only have 1 child tag inside the `<template>` tag. That's most likely the error you're seeing

Comment: Actually, I use v3 but like I said the code works perfectly